# Methods of adjusting for multiple seasonality

Tags: regression, time-series, python, seasonality, multiple-seasonalities

I am trying to remove seasonality from a dataset. What I am interested in is the residuals, as trend and seasonal influence do not matter to the problem at hand. I am using the `statsmodels` package in python. Specifically, "[Multiple Seasonal-Trend decomposition using LOESS (MSTL)](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/mstl_decomposition.html)", as there are multiple seasonalities in the dataset. Is there a better way to handle the multiple seasonalities in a dataset than this?

Comment: Sorry for removing the polite phrases; we try to get right to the point here on Cross Validated.